# one-to-many link on a subclass object

Tags: java, orm, ormlite

I have 3 simple ORM classes (java + ormlite)

A

```
@DatabaseTable
public class A extends BaseDaoEnabled {
    A(){
        bs = new ArrayList<B>();
    }

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager=true)
    public Collection<B> bs;
}
```

B

```
@DatabaseTable
public class B extends BaseDaoEnabled {
    B(){}

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true)
    A a;
}
```

C

```
@DatabaseTable
public class C extends A{
    @DatabaseField
    int x;
}
```

A one to many B. C extends A.

I can write

```
B b = new B();
b.a = new C();
```

But when I eval query there was an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class B for field 'bs' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class C
```

How can I set link on a object of a extended class (without need a property on every subclass)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Can you show the query you are building?

Comment: The message seems to indicate that `bs` is a `Collection<C>` or is a collection of the _sub_ class.  Just to make sure, it must be _B_ and not _C_ that is your foreign collection.